# An error occurred! Unable to start in just one database on server

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am running neo 4.2.9-enterprise with multiple databases.
All except one of the databases is starting up.
I get this message when I restarted the server where prod_db is the name of the database.

> An error occurred! Unable to start `DatabaseId{983937d7[prod_db]}`

THis is what I see when I run

```
show databases
```

This is a valuable database.
I don't want to lose all that data.

What is the process of debugging the issue and how do I recover the most I can ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [more detailed logs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/logging/) you should be looking at to debug this. I would start with neo4j.log and then debug.log if that doesn't answer your question.